# How to handel ValueChangeEvent getNewValue() and getOldValue()?

Tags: jsf

In my application there are several drop-down boxes each mapped with ValueChangeListner so when any value changes from the drop-down, the ValueChangeEvent was fired and searches for all the methods in the controller layer who takes ValueChangeEvent as an argument.

1. This is how I initialize the drop-down for which I am getting error

   ```
   private void methodForDropDown1(){
   bean.setValue(null);
   List<String> datas=new ArrayList<>();
   datas.add("val1");
   datas.add("val2");
   datas.add("val3");
   List<SelectItem> tableData = buildSelectionItems(datas);//takes String and returns SelectItem
   datas.setComboBox(tableData);
   ```

   }
2. This is how I am handling the ValueChangeEvent

   ```
   public void comboBoxDropDown1(ValueChangeEvent event) {
   if(event.getOldValue()==null){
       return;
   }
   try {
       if (event.getNewValue()!=null) {
   ```

   process event
   }
3. Problem with me that if after server start at the first time if I click on any other drop-down box then the drop-down I have mentioned here, was initialized and event.getNewValue() -> val1,
   but if I click on the drop-down then it is not taking the event.getOldValue() it is showing null.

in the page by default it shows val1 when the page was loaded, so by assuming that, this is the new value if I select val2/val3 then it is taking these values as getNewValue() but as expected it is not taking va1 as getOldValue().

Comment: We are using javax.faces-2.1.21

Comment: Hi BalusC Thanks for replaying, I follow the link suggested by you but my application is spring+ JSF integration and the bean is declared like {@Component
@Scope(value = "session") and I can not change the scope to @ManagedBean
@ViewScoped}